# Fusion 360 : VirtualBox: the best settings for performance?

Tags: virtualbox, performance, settings, gpu

I have now set up with VirtualBox under Ubuntu 20.04 a Windows machine 10 Pro with Fusion 360.

The performance is not quite so good, what optimizations can you recommend here that I can get more performance?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I only have Ubuntu guests, but for them, ticking Settings/Storage/Controller:SATA/
Use Host I/O Cache makes a huge difference.

Comment: This depends on which kind of machine you are running the VMs on and not the OS. The more efficient your PC is, the more apps and VMs you can run. To run VMs efficiently on PCs, you should have at least Memory capacity of 8 GB but a 16 GB runs with greater efficiency. If you have 4 GB Memory capacity on your PC, you might not run VMs efficiently, and it might not even load up if you try to start.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Ask Ubuntu so I apologize if my answer isn't useful.

I've been doing some "VM-ing" lately and I can suggest you to:

- Give the Windows guest a bit of CPU cores: this will definitely boost the performance a lot.
- Give it a little bit more RAM too, if you can.
- Consider enabling 3D acceleration under "Display" in VirtualBox: I do not recommend this as VirtualBox doesn't handle 3D accelleration very well, but you can try :)
- If you choose to enable 3D acceleration, try giving the VM a bit more video memory.
- Under "Storage", click on the virtual hard disk and check the "Solid-state Drive" option: SSDs are usually faster than normal Hard Disks and this might significantly boost the VM's performance.

When I create a VM, I usually make sure to do all these things.

Hope this helps, let me know if you need help,
have a nice one!

Comment: unfortantly i doesn't help very much :/